# Offline Gmail extension for Google Chrome doesn't work offline

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

I downloaded the Google Chrome application called "Offline Google Mail" by Google. I used it a few times (online), it works fine, syncs, whatever.

Yesterday I was on the bus and decided to give a try to Offline GMail in the real world. Except all I got was something like "Web application is not reachable". If I read this correctly, it's complaining that I am offline.

Do I have to be online for Offline to work? What is the point of Offline Gmail then?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be automaticly ready to work offline. Did you follow [these instructions](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=97535)?

Comment: This link is for Google Gears, which is being discontinued - I am talking about the new version (they mention it on top of that page "support for offline in gmail is changing")

Comment: Maybe have to turn off wifi entirely...maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem in the past. It is working for me now.

Install [offline gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk) at the Chrome Web Store (sounds like you've done that)

Use it from this url: https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/mp/601/?mui=ca#tl/Inbox or by opening a new tab in Chrome, finding offline gmail, and clicking it.